# json array parse error, the application completed without reading the entire request body

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm stuck for more than 4 hours on the issue. My json seens to be fine, at least to jsonLint, here is an example:

```
[{
    "cnpj": "1",
    "notasPorConsulta": "1",
    "partirDe": "1"
}, {
    "cnpj": "2",
    "notasPorConsulta": "2",
    "partirDe": "2"
}]
```

or

```
{
    "NovoRastreio": [{
        "cnpj": "1",
        "notasPorConsulta": "1",
        "partirDe": "1"
    }, {
        "cnpj": "2",
        "notasPorConsulta": "2",
        "partirDe": "2"
    }]
}
```

Here is how I'm posting with javascript.

```
(async () => {
        console.log(NovoRastreio);
        const fetchResp = await fetch('api/values/NovoRastreio', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: NovoRastreio
        })
        .then();
            .then(res => console.log(res.json()));
    })();
```

I also tried without async/await. No success.

First I created a basic model, after I generated another one using QuickType, here it is.

```
public partial class NovoRastreio
    {
        [JsonProperty("NovoRastreio")]
        public List<NovoRastreioElement> Rastreios { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class NovoRastreioElement
    {
        [JsonProperty("cnpj")]
        public string Cnpj { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("notasPorConsulta")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long NotasPorConsulta { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("partirDe")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long PartirDe { get; set; }
    }
```

And my controller, I removed all the code, and left just a simple console writer to see if it would work.

```
[HttpGet("NovoRastreio")]
        public void NovoRastreioPorCnpj([FromBody]NovoRastreio rastreios )
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(rastreios);
        }
```

Nope, I get the error from the tittle every time, even if I try to use postman, and also, I have multiple others posts in this same API and it works fine, the different is that the other just post a single JSON object, instead of a list/array of multiple objects.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you stated `[JsonProperty("NovoRastreio")]` in your `class NovoRastreio` but in your json there is no field with such name.
Try send something like this:

```
{
  "NovoRastreio":
    [{
        "cnpj": "1",
        "notasPorConsulta": "1",
        "partirDe": "1"
    }, {
        "cnpj": "2",
        "notasPorConsulta": "2",
        "partirDe": "2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this way, I edited my question.

Comment: @GAltelino what is yours `ParseStringConverter`? Why are your models `partial`? Remove `[JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]` and try again. It worked for me with Postman.

Comment: @GAltelino can't help you cause it should work. Try create new WebAPI project, create manually your models and use Postman. I did it and it worked for me.